# How to implement an opaque handle in C#

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I'm writing a library to be used by several applications.

Some interfaces which my library declares and uses, and which are implemented by the application, look something like this:

```
interface IOpaqueHandle : IDisposable {}

interface IPaintFactory
{
    IOpaqueHandle Create(string configData);
}

interface IPainter
{
    void Paint(IOpaqueHandle handle);
}
```

The `Create` method with `configData` parameter tells the application to allocate some resources and return a handle to those resources:

- My library doesn't know what types of resource are allocated by the application, nor exactly what methods those resources support.
- The resources probably come from various 3rd-party application-specific library, known to the application but not known by my library.
- `Create` will be called multiple times with different parameter values, to allocate different resources each with their own `IOpaqueHandle` instance

The `Paint` method is an example of telling the application to do something with a specified resource.

---

My question is, **what's the best way to implement the handle-to-resource mapping in the application?**

For example, assuming that the application's resources are defined by a class named `Resources`, I can think of two ways to implement it.

1. Using a subclass with an upcast:

   ```
   class Resource : IOpaqueHandle
   {
       internal static Resource getResource(IOpaqueHandle handle)
       {
           return (Resource)handle;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Using a dictionary to map from the handle to the object:

   ```
   class Resource : IDisposable
   {
       internal static Resource getResource(IOpaqueHandle handle)
       {
           return s_dictionary[handle];
       }

       class Handle : IOpaqueHandle
       {
           public void Dispose()
           {
               Resource resource = getResource(this);
               resource.Dispose();
               s_dictionary.Remove(this);
           }
       }

       static Dictionary<IOpaqueHandle, Resource> s_dictionary =
           new Dictionary<IOpaqueHandle, Resource>();

       internal static IOpaqueHandle Create(string configData);
       {
           Handle handle = new Handle();
           Resource resource = new Resource(configData);
           s_dictionary.Add(handle, resource);
           return handle;
       }

       Resource(string configData) { ... }
   }
   ```

**Is the subclass with an upcast simpler (to implement) and faster (at run-time) and therefore preferable?**

**Does the second solution have any advantages? It avoids an upcast, for what's that worth -- is that good?**

---

(First edit)

You might suggest declaring `Paint` as a method of the handle interface --
BUT that's not possible because of different lifetimes:

- An `IOpaqueHandle` is a long-lived object, e.g. created once at object startup
- An `IPainter` is a short-lived object, e.g. a new one is created each time the O/S window needs repainting.

A short-lived `IPainter` instance is created by the application and passed-in to my library, which calls its `Paint` method. The implementation of `IPainter` contains some short lived resources. The `Paint` method must combine the short-lived resources (contained in the IPainter) with the long-lived resources (contained in the handle).

Theoretically I could declare a method like this, instead of putting the `Paint` method in the `IPainter` interface:

```
interface IOpaqueHandle
{
    // paint using short-lived resources contained in IPainter
    void Paint(IPainter painter);
}
```

... but that amounts to the same problem, i.e. how to extract implementation-specific resources from the opaque `IPainter` interface.

---

(Second edit)

At the risk of making this question too long, here's some sample code.

The following code is in the library, in addition to the interfaces declared at the top.

```
class Node
{
    internal readonly IOpaqueHandle handle;

    // plus a lot of other data members
    // e.g. to determine whether this node is visible and should be painted

    internal Node(string configData, IPaintFactory factory)
    {
        // get the handle which we'll pass back to the application if we paint this node
        handle = factory.Create(configData);
    }

    internal bool IsVisible { get { ... } }
}

// facade
public class MyLibrary
{
    List<Node> nodes = new List<Node>();

    // initialize data using config data,
    // and using app-specific paint factory passed-in by application
    public void Initialize(List<string> configStrings, IPaintFactory factory)
    {
        configStrings.ForEach(configData => nodes.Add(new Node(configData, factory)));
    }

    // plus a lot of other methods to manipulate the Nodes

    // called from application when its window wants repainting
    public void OnPaint(IPainter painter)
    {
        nodes.ForEach(node => { if (node.IsVisible) painter.Paint(node.handle); });
    }
}
```

The above is a simplification. Because `Node` and `MyLibrary` are actually hundreds of classes, it wouldn't be convenient to wrap them all in a single generic class so that they share a common template parameter of type `T`.

The following code is in the application.
All the types in the `Os` namespace belong to some library
which the application is using and which my library doesn't know about.

```
class Resource : IOpaqueHandle
{
    readonly Os.Font font;
    readonly string text;

    internal Resource(string configData) { ... }

    // app-specific method using app-specific types
    // which my library doesn't know about and which
    // therefore isn't declared in the library's IOpaqueHandle interface
    internal void GraphicalPaint(Os.Graphics graphics)
    {
        graphics.DrawText(this.font, this.text);
    }
}

class PaintFactory : IPaintFactory
{
    public IOpaqueHandle Create(string configData)
    {
        return new Resource(configData);
    }
}

class Painter : IPainter, IDisposable
{
    internal readonly Os.Graphics graphics;

    internal Painter(Os.Graphics graphics)
    {
        this.graphics = graphics;
    }

    public void Dispose() { graphics.Dispose(); }

    public void Paint(IOpaqueHandle handle)
    {
        // use magic in question to retrieve app-specific resource from opaque handle
        Resource resource = (Resource)handle;

        // invoke app-specific method to paint this resource
        resource.GraphicalPaint(this.graphics);
    }
}

class Main : Os.Window
{
    MyLibrary myLibrary = new MyLibrary();

    void initialize(List<string> configStrings)
    {
        PaintFactory paintFactory = new PaintFactory();
        myLibrary.Initialize(configStrings, paintFactory);
    }

    // plus other methods to poke the data in MyLibrary

    // event handler called from Os when Window needs repainting
    void onPaint(Os.Graphics graphics)
    {
        using (Painter painter = new Painter(graphics))
        {
            myLibrary.OnPaint(painter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need the opaque handle at all?  It's not a very object-oriented way of designing a system, and it would probably be easier to use if the `Paint` method was supplied as a method of the returned object, for example.  Even if the object you return doesn't include the methods that use it, it can just delegate to them, at which point you have a useful object rather than a handle.

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. What is Resource? What is GetResource? How does the first snippet relate to the two options when names seem completely different?

Comment: @Jules Yes I'm thinking about that. It's because `IPainter` defines a lot of other methods as well, which don't depend on those allocated resource parameters ... so I put all those painting methods in one interface, instead of putting some of them in the resource-specific interface.

Comment: @Jules I updated the question to explain why I don't think that's possible.

Comment: Why do you use generic IOpaqueHandler? Why aren't you creating and consuming specific PaintResource? Possibly one that implements IDisposable?

Comment: @Euphoric My library (which defines IOpaqueHandle) is abstract and doesn't know about specific PaintResource types (defined by the application). There are several ways to implement painting, several applications each with different implementations of IOpaqueHandle.

Comment: I don't understand. What is your library supposed to do? What is expected from the library and what from the ones using?

Comment: @Euphoric My library contains logic for deciding what (abstract paint) to paint where. The application implements the painting using specific implementation of paint. My library defines interfaces (implemented by the application), calls factory methods (implemented by the application) to create instances of those interfaces, chooses from among the various (abstract) instances, and calls methods of those interfaces.

Comment: In the end it seems to me a simple question: upcast from a handle? Or, is there any reason to prefer to map from a handle, using a Dictionary?

Comment: its not clear to me how these objects are called and why they fail. Can you provide some of the app code and explain where the issue occurs?

Comment: So far as I know, neither solution fails. I just wonder which (if either) is better. Normally I try to avoid upcasting. But upcasting is supported by the language. So go ahead and upcast, or is there some reason to prefer the Dictionary implementation?

Comment: i mean its not clear what problem your solutions solve.

Comment: IOpaqueHandler has no methods, what would a paint implementation do with it

Comment: @Ewan IOpaqueHandle is a handle which represents (or identifies) an application's Resource instance. The application's IPaintFactory implementation creates Resource instances and returns handles of type IOpaqueHandle to my library. The library passes IOpaqueHandle instances to IPainter to specify which Resource should be used for painting. The problem I'm trying to solve (and which is implemented using the two solutions shown) is how the application's IPainter implementation converts (via upcast or using a Dictionary) the IOpaqueHandle instance back to a Resource instance.

Comment: whats not clear without some app code is why it needs to, why you cant use generics and whether there is a alternative which avoids your library creating the resources

Comment: with your very limited code you've painted us all into a corner if you'll excuse the pun

Comment: Did you think that instead of explicitly creating the resources, you could cache them? Basically it would be `Paint(string configData)` and if resource for `configData` doesn't exist, it is created and if it exists, it is reused. Then you can have `IDispose` on `IPaintFactory`.

Comment: Unless you are doing a bunch of cross-language interop/communication, this handle business provides no benefit. Are you doing that?

Answer (score 1):

The Plain answer is that any kind of mapping or up-casting is bad as it risks a run time error when it could otherwise be prevented by strongly typed classes.

Edit: OP included app code.

The solution is Generics, which allow you to specify a Type that your library has no knowledge of.

```
IPaintFactory<T>
{
    IOpaqueHandle<T> Create(config);
}

IOpaqueHandle<T>
{
    T Resource {get;}
}
```

This allows the app to specific the type of resource underneath the handler. painter can then be:

```
App.Painter : IPainter<App.MyResource>
{
    void Paint(IOpaqueHandle<App.MyResource> handle)
    {
        handle.Resource.MySecretPaintMethod(); 
    }
}
```

In Your case the type you need to use but the library doesn't know about is `OS.Graphics`.

Because the library class itself has the method which needs this type `myLibrary.OnPaint` The library will need to be a generic type. The Generic type parameter propagates up to where this function is specified.

Possibly you could refactor so that some sub class of library has the OnPaint method, then you could limit the generics to that sub type.

Comment: This feels to me like you are trading one evil (runtime casting) with another evil (generics where they don't really fit). Generics might not be usable if he has more than ~3 resource types. Because IPaintFactory would need to have all of them.

Comment: *shrug* I was going to upvote your answer before it was deleted. I dont think there is enough info to really solve the problem, and if there was it would prob be a redesign of the whole thing, not fiddling with the interfaces

Comment: Sorry I don't see how generics helps: the library can't use these interfaces (e.g. it cannot call Create to get a IOpaqueHandle<T>) for any specific T, because the library doesn't know what type T is. The type (e.g. Resource) is known to the application (or subclass), but is not known to the library. Another problem is that in C# (as opposed to C++), I think it's dubious whether Painter can call MySecretPaintMethod on any type T (unless the template specified that T is `where` some interface that publishes MySecretPaintMethod).

Comment: Generics are indeed the way to go, but the generic type shouldn't be a parameter to `IOpaqueHandle`, it serves the exact same purpose and therefore replaces it.

Comment: @BenVoigt I agree, I'm assuming in the actual code there is some extra stuff on IOpaqueHandle

Comment: @ChrisW The library can use those interfaces fine. It doesnt need the T except to enforce that the correct IOpaqueHander is passed to the IPainter

Comment: If the library defines a generic interface like
    `interface IOpaqueHandle<T>
    {
        T Resource { get; }
    }`
it cannot store an instance of that interface e.g. like
    `struct Data
    {
        IOpaqueHandle<T> Handle;
    }`
unless it specifies what type `T` is. But the library doesn't know what type T is. For this to work I think the whole library would need to be a generic class of type T.

Comment: @ChrisW sure, but your example doesnt have that requirement. Hence my request for more code

Comment: @Ewan I posted more code FYI.

Answer (score 0):

OK You **did** include the critical myLibrary.Onpaint() function, but here's How I would refactor your new code to avoid the needless casting, generics even though it totally solves you issue, and adding the factory to the resource handler.

So this will be solution 3.

I kinda feel you are just going to go "oh that wouldn't work because.. adds more code"

```
class Main : Os.Window
{
    MyLibrary myLibrary = new MyLibrary();
    PaintFactory paintFactory;
    void initialize(List<string> configStrings)
    {
        paintFactory = new PaintFactory();
        myLibrary.Initialize(configStrings, paintFactory);
    }

    // plus other methods to poke the data in MyLibrary

    // event handler called from Os when Window needs repainting
    void onPaint(Os.Graphics graphics)
    {
        foreach(var r in paintFactory.ResList)
        {
            r.graphics = graphics;
        }

        myLibrary.OnPaint();
    }
}
```

Edit: Jeeze I missed the nodes. OK well you just have to switch it around and set the Os.Graphics on each resource

```
public void OnPaint()
{
    nodes.ForEach(node => { if (node.IsVisible) node.handle.Paint(); });
}

class Resource : IOpaqueHandle
{
    readonly Os.Font font;
    readonly string text;

    internal Resource(string configData) { }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    // app-specific method using app-specific types
    // which my library doesn't know about and which
    // therefore isn't declared in the library's IOpaqueHandle interface
    internal void GraphicalPaint(Os.Graphics graphics)
    {
        graphics.DrawText(this.font, this.text);
    }

    public PaintFactory parent;
    public Os.Graphics graphics { get; set; }
    public void Paint()
    {
        GraphicalPaint(graphics);
    }
}
```

Pretty ugly way to avoid generics though

Comment: I understand what you're suggesting, thank you, yes, that would work too.

Answer (score 0):

You can sometimes implement this (i.e. dispatching on two base types to get the leaf types) using "[double-dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch)". But I think you can't do that in this case, though, because the base types or interfaces (owned by the library) cannot name the leaf types implemented by the application.

In this case, if you're going to use the `Dictionary` method to get the leaf `Resource` type, it would be better (more conventional) to use a value type as the `Dictionary` key, instead using of a methodless interface as an opaque handle (i.e. using a reference type as a dictionary key).

- Name the value `resourceId` or something like that.
- The type of the value could be `int` or `Guid`; or, for type-safety and to help make the API self-documenting, a custom value type like `struct ResourceId { int idValue; ... }`.

So:

```
interface IPaintFactory
{
    // create the resource and return a resource id
    int Create(string configData);
}

interface IPainter
{
    void Paint(int resourceId);
}
```

I'm not sure what the argument against upcasting (instead of using a `Dictionary`) is.

- It seems safe enough -- if the application is the only software in the process that's creating objects derived from `IOpaqueHandle` i.e. `Resource` objects, then surely it's safe to assume that every `IOpaqueHandle` instance *isa* `Resource` instance.
- And I guess that upcasting might be microscopically faster than doing a dictionary lookup.
- And the `Dictionary` needs to be maintained by the application, and the lifetime of dictionary entries needs to be managed -- with the "handle" method, the library stores the handles and can `Dispose` each handle when its no longer needed, instead of the library storing IDs (keys) and using another custom API (other than `Dispose`) to tell the application to clear the `Dictionary` entry and dispose the corresponding `Resource`.

In the end though a dictionary with an ID may be better even if it's theoretically worse (slower and more complicated) than upcasting from a handle -- because apparently some programmers think that upcasting is the devil, and assume that if you're doing it then you're doing it wrong and there must be some alternative.